# Setting flags before running python code on Jupyter

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I need to run this line of code in my Jupyter notebook that sets THEANO_FLAGS before running python code.

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32' python ./networkTraining.py ./LiviaNET_Config.ini
```

If I run the above code on my command line, it gets executed successfully.

However, How do I translate this to a Jupyter notebook compatible code?

Running it as two seperate commands like so

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32' 
%run -i  src/networkTraining.py src/LiviaNET_Config.ini 0
```

fails to set the flag as it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: ('TensorType(float32, scalar)
```

This error can be resolved by setting the flag in the command line.

Comment: Try `export THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32'`.

Comment: doing this inside jupyter gives an invalid syntax error